# Building UE4 from source - Mathcalls syntax errors

Tags: c++, bash, build, unreal-engine4, debian-stretch

I'm trying to build UE4 from source on my Debian (stretch) system.

I've followed all of the instructions from [the official guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html), but running `make` gives some nasty errors from UE4's bundled mathcalls header.

Here is my log:
https://pastebin.com/4iMM7G4w

I've tried following the guide again from the start (including re-downloading the source), and I've (unsuccessfully) tried to update to clang-7; but I've just seen that clang is actually bundled with UE4, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Thanks in advance, any help is very much appreciated.

---

UPDATE: Compiling was able to continue when running with superuser privileges, `sudo make`.
However, it looks like the makefile realizes it has root privileges and cancels the build because of it - see line 49 in this log: https://pastebin.com/rH34Fv06

Comment: Which branch are you building from? Try a working release build maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using the release branch, version 4.22.3. The exact same process worked perfectly on my other (Ubuntu) system, so it's something to do with my Debian setup i feel..